"too much recursion" error in vue.js when mutating apexcharts options with responsive
In vue (3.2.13), responsive options on apexcharts (3.53.0) appear to cause recursion as soon as a mutation takes place of the options object.
In the example below, console logging succeeds before the attempted mutation, but then the colour change does not take place. Eventually, the second console log happens immediately before the error is output to console, and displayed in an overlay. Upon closing the overlay, I see my chart is no longer visible.
I know there are probably CSS workarounds for many of the responsive changes, but it'd be good to understand why this causes a problem.
As far as I can tell, this relates to mutations of options, rather than specifically changing .colors.
In the vue template:
<apexchart ref="myApex" class="chart" height="100%" type="line" :options="optionsData" :series="seriesData"></apexchart>

In the script:
methods: {
    updateOptionsData() {
        this.optionsData = {
            chart: {
                id: this.chartId,
                height: '100%',
            },
            responsive: [ 
                { // problem does NOT occur if I remove {}, so that responsive is empty []
                    breakpoint: 768,
                    options: {
                        tooltip: { // problem still occurs if I remove all contents of options {}
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
        };
    },
},
mounted() {
    this.updateOptionsData();
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            console.log(237);
            this.optionsData = {
                ...this.optionsData,
                colors: ['#000000', '#666666', '#AAAAAA', '#FFFFFF'],
            };
            console.log(238);
        },
        5000,
    );
},

Note: this problem also occurs if I do this in setTimeout instead:
            this.$refs.myApex.updateOptions({
                colors: ['#000000', '#666666', '#AAAAAA', '#FFFFFF'],
            });

Potentially useful info. If I do the following, it seems to have no effect. So it neither causes the recursion (with responsive), nor changes the colours on the chart (without responsive):
            this.optionsData.colors = ['#000000', '#666666', '#AAAAAA', '#FFFFFF'];

Error output:

Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
too much recursion
ownKeys@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1040:5
value@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:5:7558
value@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:5:7592
value@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:5:7592
value@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:5:7437
value@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:5:7592
… (then the line ending 5:7592 repeats another 122 times)


I have the same issue.. I opened an issue on the vue3-apexcharts Github page with a reproduction link.
You can find it there: https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts/issues/125
My example is slightly different but the result is the same..
If you find a workaround, let me know.

I actually found a workaround using vueuse composable useBreakpoints and a computed. You can read more there: https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts/issues/125#issuecomment-2414308080
